# Конструкция try/catch. Проблемы с FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, try-catch

Требуется считать xls файл. Но try никогда не выполняется, а выполняется условие из catch. В итоге bb={“0,0,0,0”}. Не могу понять, что я делаю не так. Файл лежит в папке проекта.

Перемещение файла в другое место, изменение имени ничего не дало. Думала, что дело в том, что это xls, но даже с txt тоже самое.

```
Book bb = new Book();
String[] mas = bb.boob();

public class Book {
    public String[] data = new String[4];

    public String[] boob() {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("list.xls")) {
            //Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                data[i] = "1";
            }
            fis.close();
            return data;
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            String[] d ={"0","0","0","0"};
            return d;}
    }
    }
```

Comment: именно поэтому IDE автоматически вставляют e.printStackTrace(); в блок catch, который четко скажет, в чем проблема.

Comment: Я думаю, что файл все же не лежит в папке проекта. Перепроверьте. Я пробовала, у меня try сработал.

Comment: Проверьте где программа ищет этот файл с помощью `System.out.println(new File("list.xls" ).getCanonicalPath())`. Чудес не бывает - если файл не находится, значит его там нет.

Comment: Конструкция `try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("list.xls"))` называется `try-with-resources` и автоматически закрывает созданные для неё ресурсы. Возможно ошибка возникает при повторном закрытии fis (Сначала закрываете вы, а затем автоматически блок try)

Comment: @Alexandr убрала, все равно try не выполняется.

Comment: @WeNeedToGoDeeper пишет: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). Я понимаю, что он не может найти файл или директорию, но не понимаю почему. Файл точно в папке проекта.Я уже сто раз проверяла и проект пересоздавала.

Comment: Проблема на андроиде? Там же нет понятия "файл в папке проекта", все рассовывается по ресурсам и т.п.

Comment: Всем спасибо, я разобралась. Оказывается надо было файл открывать используя assets. Например, fis = getAssets().open("list.xls");
Всем большое спасибо за помощь с:

Comment: Может, запишите этот комментарий в ответ и отметьте его как верный, чтобы будущим читателям было проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо было файл открывать используя assets. Например, fis = getAssets().open("list.xls");